# How to return a list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm taking an optimization class in C++ and have been trying to recode the labs in Haskell for kicks and giggles.  The going has been rough but very interesting.

I'm trying to write a function that returns a list of 3 Integer tuples like so:

`[(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,2)]`

Here is the code I've been attempting to use:

```
sortToTuples :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int -> Int -> [(Int,Int,a)]
sortToTuples [] _ _ = []
-- i and j are passed as 1 and 1.
sortToTuples (x:xs) i j   
    | j > 9         = [(i+1, 1, x)] ++ sortToTuples (xs i+1 1)
    | otherwise     = [(i, j+1, x)] ++ sortToTuples (xs i, j+1)
```

The function is meant to take a flat list that represents a sudoku puzzle and return a list of tuples (i,j,x) where i is the row value, j is the column value, and x is the value of the cell.

For whatever reason haskell is very unhappy with my type signature:

```
Prelude> :l quicksort.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( quicksort.hs, interpreted )

quicksort.hs:23:44:
    Couldn't match expected type `[(Int, Int, a)]'
                with actual type `Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, a0)]'
    In the return type of a call of `sortToTuples'
    Probable cause: `sortToTuples' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `sortToTuples (xs i + 1 1)'
    In the expression: [(i + 1, 1, x)] ++ sortToTuples (xs i + 1 1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Comment: try `sortTuples xs (i+1) 1` instead of `sortTuples (xs i+1 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bit of a syntax error here

```
| j > 9 = [(i+1, 1, x)] ++ sortToTuples (xs i+1 1)
| otherwise = [(i, j+1, x)] ++ sortToTuples (xs i, j+1)
```

You almost have it correct, it should be

```
... sortToTuples xs (i+1) 1
... sortToTuples xs i (j+1)
```

That way each argument is passed separately to `sortToTuples`.

To explain the compiler error, it sees `(xs i+1 1)` as a single argument, and since it parses are correct Haskell, it thinks that the first argument to `sortToTuples` should have type `[a]`, so it thinks that `sortToTuples (xs i+1 1)` should have type `Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, a)]`.

Comment: @SteelNation No problem, sometimes you just need another set of eyes looking at your code to catch the simple errors.